Where exactly is the bootloader installed?
I have two disks, the first with an NVMe controller and Windows 10. The second disk uses a SCSI controller, and I want to install Ubuntu on it. The disk and partition table recognized by the Ubuntu installer is shown in the figure below.
Partition table of the first disk (/dev/nvme0n1):

Partition table of the second disk (/dev/sda):

EFI partition, both in the disk partition is /dev/nvme0n1p1, /dev/sda3. The location of device for boot loader installation is /dev/sda3(efi). When I went into Ubuntu, I found /boot/efi is in /dev/nvme0n1p1 (efi partition of the first disk). And there's nothing in /dev/sda3.
/boot/efi :

I wonder what causes this. When installing a dual system, the boot bootloader should be installed on a disk or an efi partition on the disk, and what is the difference between the two?

You haven't provided details as to what Ubuntu product, or what ISO/installer you're asking about.  Where the bootloader is written will depend on how the ISO is written to media (all QA testing assumes a simple clone which creates a known environment on install media; alternate writing methods can influence bootloader location so be aware of how you write ISO & follow official docs for best results), how install media is booted etc...  If legacy boot the ESP isn't used for bootloader, but MBR is used; if uEFI the ESP is used

Ubuntu Server uses subiquiy installer, Ubuntu Desktop varies on release; 22.04 used ubiquity, 23.10 offered two installers being ubiquity and ubuntu-desktop-installer, where 24.04 only offered ubuntu-desktop-installer.  Other Ubuntu flavors can also use calamares but you haven't provided Ubuntu details...

For Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 desktops, See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.

I have seen the related case notes, this should be a bug, so far in the Ubuntu-22.04 release is still fixed. I found the same thing in debian-12.

You can edit fstab with UUID of ESP on sda3.
lsblk -f 
 sudoedit /etc/fstab 

After edit of fstab always check it has no errors. If it just comes back its ok.
sudo mount -a 

Then just reinstall grub and it will use ESP mounted in fstab. Make sure mount has updated, the mount -a should have updated, but best to check.
sudo grub-install 

You also can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose install drive. Default with a working system, will just reinstall to existing ESP, that is in fstab.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
